# indent on \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, indentation

My LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}

\begin{document}
This is an introduction.

\setlength{\leftskip}{3cm}
This is a sub-chapter

\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}

The bibliography is printed here:

\setlength{\leftskip}{3cm}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}

This is the conclusion

\end{document}
```

The contents of lib.bib are:

```
    @article{article1,
    author =       "author1",
    title =        "title1",
    journal =       "journal1",
    year =          "2007",
    url =           "library.com/334"
}

@conference{conference2,
    author =       "W",
    journal =    "bookt",
    title =        "title2",
    year =          "2008"
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Indenting works only on "Reference" while the rest of the bibliography indentation is inharmonic with the document.

How to make indenting work on `\printbibliography`?

Comment: Your \leftskip setting won't work together with lists (as \printbibliography uses a list, it is one example of such a failure). What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: The indentation of the bibliography listing should be equal to that of "This is a sub-chapter"

Comment: That was not my question. What are you trying to achieve with the leftskip setting at the "this is a sub chapter"? As a general indentation command it won't work!

Comment: I use \leftskip to indent.

Comment: Why not quote or some other list?

Comment: What do you mean by "quote" and "some other list"?

Answer (score 5):

Simply add the `\leftskip` indent to `\leftmargin` in the definition of the `bibliography` environment.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\leftskip}%<----- here
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```